# Any way to specify a java generic type variable that extends any one of multiple classes?

Tags: java, generics

So suppose I have 2 classes:

```
public class A
{
  public void
  f()
  {
  }
}

public class B
{
  public void
  f()
  {
  }
}
```

I would like to write a generic static method that could call f when passed an instance of A or B.  I tried:

```
public class C
{
  public static <T extends A & B> void
  g(T t)
  {
    t.f();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    A a = new A();

    g(a);
  }
}
```

But the compiler claims A is not a valid substitute for "T extends A & B", which I assume is because T must extend BOTH A and B, which obviously A does not.  I could not find a way to specify something like "T extends A OR B".  Is something like this not achievable? I am a java neophyte, so any help with this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can only specify one generic type. **Use interfaces instead.**

An interface specifies a certain set of methods, each member of it has to have. A class can implement multiple interfaces.

In your example, I would define an interface with the method `f()`:

```
public interface MyInterface {
  void f();
}
```

Let `A` and `B` implement the interface:

```
public class A implements MyInterface
{
  @Override
  public void f() {
    // ...
  }
}
public class B implements MyInterface
{
  @Override
  public void f() {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Then you can just specify the interface as type of the argument for your method:

```
public static void g(MyInterface obj)
{
  obj.f();
}
```

For more detail on interfaces, check the Java documentation: [What Is an Interface?](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html)

Comment: Thanks for your input.  I guess I should have been a little more precise - I am looking to use the generic static method with 3rd party classes that I cannot modify.  These classes have no common interface I can use, but for some reason, they all implement the same functions.  I was trying to consolidate some repetitive method coding that currently requires overloading for each class into one method.

Comment: I also realize I could finesse this by wrapping the 3rd party classes in a class the implements the common methods and simply delegates to the 3rd party class methods, but I was hoping to avoid this clunkiness via some clever use of generics :)

Comment: @MistahMikey You could use reflection for that: `clazz.getMethod("f").invoke(obj)`.

Comment: @MistahMikey If you can contact the 3rd party and recommend adding a shared interface or series of interfaces, I'd recommend doing so. It doesn't directly solve your problem, but could help other users of those classes and could help their developers improve.